# Compare two data frames and identify duplicates based on rows

Tags: r, dataframe

How to identify the duplicate rows based on `serial` and `day` variables from two separate df? I tried to create an unique variable but without success.

Desired output:

[image]

Data structure:

```
df1
```

[image]

```
df2
```

[image]

Sample data:

```
df1<-0)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(serial = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), day = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))



df2<-structure(list(serial = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7), day = c(1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -7L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
    serial = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), day = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**base**

```r
df1 <- data.frame(serial = c(1:5), day = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0))
df2 <- data.frame(serial = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7),  day = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1))

df2$dup <- sapply(
  X = paste0(df2$serial, df2$day), 
  FUN = function(x) !is.na(match(x = x, table = paste0(df1$serial, df1$day))))

df2
#>   serial day   dup
#> 1      1   1  TRUE
#> 2      2   1 FALSE
#> 3      3   1  TRUE
#> 4      4   0  TRUE
#> 5      5   0  TRUE
#> 6      5   1 FALSE
#> 7      7   1 FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>